# Query for listing Datasets and Number of tables in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, information-schema

So I'd like make a query that shows all the datasets from a project, and the number of tables in each one. My problem is with the number of tables.

Here is what I'm stuck with :

```
SELECT
  smt.catalog_name        as `Project`,
  smt.schema_name         as `DataSet`, 
  ( SELECT
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM ***DataSet***.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  )                       as `nbTable`,
  smt.creation_time,
  smt.location
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA smt
ORDER BY DataSet
```

The view *INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA* lists all the datasets from the project the query is executed, and the view *INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES* lists all the tables from a given dataset.

The thing is that the view *INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES* needs to have the dataset specified like this give the tables informations : *dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES*

So what I need is to replace the *** DataSet*** by the one I got from the query itself (**smt.schema_name**).
I am not sure if I can do it with a sub query, but I don't really know how to manage to do it.

I hope I'm clear enough, thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using some procedural language as follows:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_counts (dataset_id STRING, table_count INT64);

FOR record IN 
  (
    SELECT 
      catalog_name as project_id,
      schema_name as dataset_id
    FROM `elzagales.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`
  )

DO 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    CONCAT("INSERT table_counts (dataset_id, table_count)  SELECT table_schema as dataset_id, count(table_name) from ", record.dataset_id,".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES GROUP BY dataset_id");

END FOR;

SELECT * FROM table_counts;
```

This will return something like:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot it is right just what i need

Comment: great if this solution helped, please consider marking the answer correct as well